# Is it possible, putting an INDEX, IF, and VLookup Formula into one using multiple spread sheets?

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, vlookup

Is this possible? I have 2 spread sheets, one with a list of items, and how many items are being requested. I have another spread sheet with the same list of items, when inventory will arrive, and how many units. I need to know at what point do we NOT have enough inventory to cover the requested amount.

I know how to do the formulas on an individual basis but do not know how to combine them. I need a formula that will look up the items, then reference a table where the column headers are the week numbers, and quantities are listed for each item. It would then do a subtraction of the requested amount, from the inventory through the specified week numbers, and populate with the corresponding week number of when the inventory for that item became negative.

I have my items listed, in one spread sheet. I need to know at what week as listed in the next spread sheet does inventory become negative, so i can say when the orders is at risk.

Any Help on this would be immensely appreciated. Even just help with breaking down the logic would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you actually need some kind if inventory management tool. =/

Comment: Agree with @pnuts. Or I'd use MS Access instead, in line with the inventory management recommendation.

Comment: Sadly my inventory management tool does not have reporting capability. We are talking thousands of order, and without looking each one up individually this is the option I have left. I will play around with the pivot. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use pivot table and Messages alert (using formulas) that alert you anytime "Product Requested" is less then "Available Product". Data Validation is what you need to search for in Excel.